# Is it possible to use Windows PE Bootable drive on OS X

Tags: bootable-disk

I am completely new to Apple machines. I have got a MacBook Pro. I want to see all available drives on the computer. The computer cannot boot into OS X.

I only know Windows PE Bootable drive. I have created a USB. How do I boot on a USB in Mac?

Comment: Does Windows PE Bootable drive even work on a Mac? If not, what do I use? I want to know what's inside the machine. I can't undo a screw which is stuck, so I can't open it. Very perplexed.

Answer (score 1):

Though it may be possible to create and boot a WinPE thumb drive on a Mac, the purpose of WinPE (or WinRE) is custom-tailored to the needs of admins/users of Windows systems/software/file systems.

Apple (and your Mac) provides its own measures to diagnose your hard- and software, so there is no need to create a Windows PE Bootable USB-thumb drive.

Depending on your Mac and your installed system you may:

- boot to your Recovery HD (hit <kbd>cmd</kbd><kbd>R</kbd> immediately after the start-up chime)
- boot to Internet Recovery Mode (hit <kbd>alt</kbd><kbd>cmd</kbd><kbd>R</kbd> immediately after the start-up chime). You need a decent internet connection though.
- use [Apple Hardware Test](http://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201257)
- use [Apple Hardware Test .dmg](https://github.com/upekkha/AppleHardwareTest)
- use [Apple Diagnostics](http://support.apple.com/en-us/HT202731)

Comment: Thanks. Do Macs have all installation image in its harddrive by default? Or it comes with a DVD when it's bought? Can you create an installation Disc from an ISO? I have no idea how the whole installation works.

Comment: @HoyCheung All Macs introduced until ~ mid 2011 (except some Mac Airs) came with several DVDs or CDs.

Comment: @HoyCheung All Macs introduced later came with preinstalled systems and apps but without any media (like DVDs). All later systems can be downloaded from the App Store. You can create bootable installer thumb drives and AFAIK DVD with those system installers. Check [apple](http://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201372)